# Debug Assertion Failed! OpenCV Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, 32-bit

This code uses OpenCV functions to detect human bodies in a video. It works fine when I run it on a 64bit platform, linking the 64 libraries.
I am having a problem running this code on a 32bit platform when I link the 32bit libraries.

I am using OpenCV 3.0 because the higher versions do not have the built 32bit libraries and dlls. Except I  found these by following this path: F:\Uni\Semester 9\Honours Thesis\Softwares\opencv_3.0\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib
I am using vc12 because there is no vc14(VS2015) for OpenCV 3.0.

When I try to run the code I get this error:

---

Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...ni\Semester 9\Honours Thesis\Scripts\6_cpu - Copy\Debug\6.exe
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0
Line:100

Expression: "(_Ptr_user & (_BIGALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT - 1)) == 0" && 0

For information on how your praogram can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)

---

The script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

VideoCapture cap;
Mat img;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{   
    float framecnt = 0, secAvg = 0, sum = 0;

    // prepare video output
    VideoWriter outputVideo;

    outputVideo.open("outputVideo.avi", -1, 15, img.size(), true);

    cap.open("http://192.168.1.2:8080/video?x.mjpeg");
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 854);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
        return -1;

    /*HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, NULL, 0, NULL);*/
    //Mat img;
    Mat imgOld;
    Mat imgCopy;
    //cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::HOG> gpu_hog = cv::cuda::HOG::create(win_size, block_size, block_stride, cell_size, args.nbins);
    HOGDescriptor hog;
    hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());

    namedWindow("video capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    while (true)
    {
        cap >> img;
        if (!img.data)
            continue;
        imgCopy = img;
        clock_t start = clock();

        vector<Rect> found, found_filtered;
        hog.detectMultiScale(img, found, 0, Size(8, 8), Size(32, 32), 1.05, 2); 

        size_t i, j;
        for (i = 0; i<found.size(); i++)
        {
            Rect r = found[i];
            for (j = 0; j<found.size(); j++)
            if (j != i && (r & found[j]) == r)
                break;
            if (j == found.size())
                found_filtered.push_back(r);
        }
        for (i = 0; i<found_filtered.size(); i++)
        {
            Rect r = found_filtered[i];
            r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1);
            r.width = cvRound(r.width*0.8);
            r.y += cvRound(r.height*0.06);
            r.height = cvRound(r.height*0.9);
            rectangle(img, r.tl(), r.br(), cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
        }

        clock_t end = clock();
        float seconds = (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cout << (seconds) << " seconds" << endl;

        double fps = 1 / seconds;
        cout << (fps) << " fps" << endl;

        //Average time taken to process each frame
        framecnt = framecnt + 1;
        sum = (sum + seconds);
        secAvg = sum / framecnt;
        cout << (framecnt) << " frames" << endl;
        cout << (secAvg) << " average time" << endl;


        imshow("video capture", imgCopy);
        outputVideo << img;
        if (cv::waitKey(1) == 'q') {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know if there is any more information I could provide.

Comment: Hi, take a look at the [tour] and [mcve] and clean up the question a bit

Comment: The dlls you have are probably not compatible with your version of Visual Studio. I recommend you to build the 32bit version of OpenCV yourself. Depending on your platform, you can have a look [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) or [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html).